# Need to see if you clicked a rectangle in a grid. (Pygame)

Tags: pygame

Basically, I created a grid with this:

```
for x in range(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, blockSize):
        for y in range(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, blockSize):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, rect, 1)
```

and I need to see if the player clicked on one of the grids. How do I do this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: [This seems to already be answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150957/pygame-action-when-mouse-click-on-rect) - found by [searching "pygame click rect"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pygame+click+rect&ia=web). Did you have any difficulty implementing the solutions you found when doing this basic research before posting a new question?

Comment: I started answering this twice before realizing that the question needs clarification.  Do you want to know *whether* a square is being clicked, which square is being clicked, whether an intersection is being clicked, or which intersection is being clicked?